# Making POST requests in google actions without Inline Cloud Functions

Tags: actions-on-google

I want to make a simple post request in google actions to a self hosted web server and I cant seem to figure out how to do that. I cant find much in the documentation and I dont have access to inline cloud functions either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is sometimes known as a *webhook* or a *handler* or handling *fulfillment* in the documentation.

You'll configure the overall Action with a single webhook URL. For specific Intents (in Dialogflow) or as part of a Handler when in a scene in Action Builder, you can specify when the webhook should be called. It will be called with a JSON body that is specific to Actions on Google (and differs if you're using Action Builder or Dialogflow) and expects a JSON response in a specific format.

For details about all of this, consult the documentation for webhooks in either [Action Builder](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/webhooks?tool=builder) or [Dialogflow](https://developers.google.com/assistant/df-asdk/dialogflow/fulfillment).